# Uninstall fonts installed using SWT's Display.loadFont API

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working under eclipse plugin and trying to load fonts into the application as resources, so they will appear in project explorer tree.

In SWT we have method loadFont of Display class which loads font from specified file, so it will appear in list of available fonts of application. I am using this method.

But when I am trying to delete the font from project explorer I am getting following exception:

> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: 
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources

I have following questions:

1. Is it possible to unload font from application in SWT ?
2. Is there any way to deal with it?
3. Is there another scenario to deal with custom fonts in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes of the type FontData don't need to be disposed of, as they simply contain a small amount of information about the font. When you create an actual Font object then yes, it is your responsibility to call .dispose() and free up those resources.

If you are using JFace as well as SWT, then you may want to look at FontRegistry, which assists in keeping track of font resources.

Apologies for not linking any javadocs, the SWT docs aren't loading for me right now. I did find [a small example of FontRegistry usage](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UsingtheFontRegistry.htm) which explains the difference between FontData and Font.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I am interested in removing font from list of application fonts. I mean font can be loaded from file to the application list of fonts by using of loadFont method of Display class. Is there any possibility to "unload" font ? Example of font loading can be founded here : http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/swt/fonts_in_swt_code.html

Comment: `shell.getDisplay().loadFont(fontFileName);` - I am a little rusty on SWT but I think this just makes the font available by name, but does not actually load it. You can then create a FontData object which just references a font by name and style options like italics or roman. In the example you linked, the font is actually loaded at this point: `return new Font(shell.getDisplay(), "Amiga Forever Pro2", fontSize, SWT.NORMAL);` You are responsible for that Font object, and should call .dispose() when you no longer need it, and at that point it is unloaded.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! Maybe my question is asked in too confusing way, so I have asked it in another way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919217/how-to-delete-font-resource-from-eclipse-plugin

Comment: Please don't do that. Clarify your original question instead. I have done some searching and have not found a way to uninstall a font via SWT. To avoid your projects resources from being locked, you may want to copy your font files to some system location and load/install from there.